# ESLint rule for preventing imports that match a pattern

Tags: javascript, eslint

Does anyone know of an ESLint rule that can flag imports that match a given regular expression?

Comment: it would be a pretty easy rule to write - I've just checked [eslint-plugin-import](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import) and it doesn't seem to have the rule you're after.

Comment: [here](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/a368326534383d56f9fb144d7a7c8f05/9bbf5d1f068cd0051deff40013d188f73e420d53) is a quick solution - you could use something like [eslint-plugin-local-rules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-local-rules) to enable it for your repository.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try **no-restricted-imports** rule. [no-restricted-imports](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-imports)